# What is the end number used for in start_mining command?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, cpu-mining

I am ready to begin mining through wallet-cli.  However, I am seeing different commands.  For example, I have seen "start_mining 4", start_mining 2", etc...

Can I just use the command start_mining?

Thanks for all of your help Miles P. and scoobybejesus!

Answer (score 2):

That number is the number of mining threads to use. If not specified, it defaults to one thread.

Typically, you'll want one thread per 2 MB of cache memory your CPU has available (so 3 threads if you have 6 MB cache, for example).

Answer (score 0):

The number is how many processes are mining. If you dont have a dedicated computer for mining put 2 or 3. Its recommended put the number of physical core for computer dedicated for mining.